# When I click on my name, and scroll to my questions, why no indication which questions have approved answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I click on my name. I scroll down to (my) questions. Many have answers. In some cases, one of the answers has been ticked or checked, meaning that I have accepted one of the answers as resolution to my question. When a question reaches that status, I would like it to be displayed somehow differently, so I don't have to browse that question again. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very much indicated. On StackOverflow, the answer count for a question with an accepted answer is printed in yellow; on questions without an accepted answer it's white. If you move your cursor over the answer count, this is also stated in the tool tip.

On SuperUser, the distinction is green background / white background; on meta it's (pale) yellow / white again. On ServerFault it's green text / white text.

Comment: But on your user page, the only questions that are highlighted are the ones where *you* have the accepted answer.  There is no indication as to whether the question has an accepted answer by someone else, which I think is Tom's point.

Comment: From the question: "...meaning that I have accepted..." "...I don't have to browse that question again..." Sounds like he's talking about his own questions.

Comment: @balpha: Fair enough.  I stand corrected.

Comment: Answer much appreciated. Now I know what to look for. I imagine that the different colors for different forums are due to the different color schemes. But I must say that the "pale yellow" is very pale! I wonder how that could be changed to make it more noticeable ...

Answer (score 0):

On your question list (questions you ask) you can immediately see the ones where you have accepted an answer.

On your answer list (questions you answered) you can immediately see the ones where you won the accepted answer.

As of yet there is no method to indicate questions you have answered which have been accepted and the accepted answer was not yours.